# CXF ignores sourceRoot configuration parameter

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, maven-plugin

I'm using CXF maven plugin to generate Java classes from wsdl

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf-codegen-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>wsdl2java</id>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>src/main/generated</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/contentprovidercallback.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-frontend</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>jaxws21</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-b</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>src/main/resources/wsdl/jaxws-contentprovidercallback.xml</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-d</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>src/main/generated</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-faultSerialVersionUID</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>FQCN</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xts</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-XhashCode</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-xjc-Xequals</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
            <version>${stax2.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.xjc.ts.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2.basics.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

when I'm trying to execute `cxf-codegen:wsdl2java` goal, generated classes are not generated in defined sourceRoot directory.

When I run `mvn` with debug options (-X -e) I'm getting:

```
...
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.1:wsdl2java from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@425224ee]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.1:wsdl2java' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = C:\WsdlTest\target\classes
[DEBUG]   (f) disableDependencyScan = false
[DEBUG]   (f) disableDirectoryScan = false
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) javaExecutable = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\jre/bin/java
[DEBUG]   (f) localRepository =        id: local
      url: file:///C:/Users/admi/.m2/repository/
   layout: none

[DEBUG]   (f) markerDirectory = C:\WsdlTest\target\cxf-codegen-plugin-markers
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@59cc5d23
[DEBUG]   (f) pluginArtifacts = [org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:maven-plugin:2.6.1:, org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.0.2:runtime, javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:runtime, org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-ts:jar:2.4.0:runtime, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics:jar:0.6.3:runtime, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-runtime:jar:0.6.3:runtime, org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-tools:jar:0.6.3:runtime, commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:runtime, org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-resolver:jar:1.0:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:1.2:compile, org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.2:runtime, org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0.2:compile, org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile, wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile, commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:jar:2.1.13:compile, com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.13:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-core:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-validator:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.6.1:compile, xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-javascript:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-javascript:jar:2.6.1:compile, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile, org.apache.ant:ant-nodeps:jar:1.8.1:compile]
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.tmobile.tmo.pfw:ssa:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ C:\WsdlTest\pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) repositories = [id = 'releases', id = 'snapshots', id = 'central']
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceRoot = C:\WsdlTest\target\generated-sources\cxf
[DEBUG]   (f) testWsdlRoot = C:\WsdlTest\src\test\resources\wsdl
[DEBUG]   (f) useCompileClasspath = false
[DEBUG]   (f) wsdlRoot = C:\WsdlTest\src\main\resources\wsdl
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
...
```

On the other hand, during `mvn clean install` sources are generated well (in generated folder). But I do not want to generate those classes each build.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is pretty old but I had the same issue and wanted to save the solution for the future:

Somehow `cxf-codegen-plugin` requires some maven phases to be executed to be able to "grab" the configuration element instead of using defaults. What I did was to remove the plugin from default build and create a profile just to be able to run it as part of the 
`generate-sources` phase on demand instead of with every build.

Mine looks like this:

```
<profile>
    <id>generate-ws-stub</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <version.cxf>2.3.0</version.cxf>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.cxf}</version>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${version.cxf}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>    

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${project.build.sourceDirectory}\prb</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${project.build.resources[0].directory}/wsdl/NoneOfYourBusinessWS.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/NoneOfYourBusinessWS.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-impl</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Now, whenever I want to "refresh" my XML binding I just run `mvn generate-sources -P generate-ws-stub`